# Global environment variable memory use to table

Tags: r

Using RStudio and looking to identify variable using most memory and clear them out before saving project session.

1. What's the best way to create a data frame with variable names and sizes?

Based on various sources, I managed to do it as follows:

```
env <- data.frame(
              "var" = ls(),
              "size" = sapply(ls(),function(x){object.size(get(x))}),
              "sizef" = sapply(ls(),function(x){format(object.size(get(x)), unit = 'auto')})
              )
```

2. What's the best way to sort the list by size and output top results?

I was able to do that with `base` subsetting. In this case, why does `order(-env$size)` work but `order(-size)` throws an error?

```
head(env[order(-env$size),],10)
```

I also made a first use of `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
env %>%
  arrange(-size) %>%
  filter(size>=1e8) %>%
  top_n(10)
```

As I'm often finding at the start of my R journey, I can't tell what is the method to be using, if any of these. In terms of clarity, speed, flexibility, ease of use, quickest to code, etc... what is best practice?

Comment: If you're using RStudio, why not simply sort objects in the Environment tab and remove them there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @joran.  I didn't know it was possible to do this.  @kavmeister, you need to select the `Grid` display of the environment, not the `List` display, to see the sizes.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way to get all variable names would be to access the global environment directly:

```
sort(sapply(.GlobalEnv, object.size)) # a sorted, named, numeric vector
```

To get the largest `n` objects, you can then use `tail`:

```
tail(sort(sapply(.GlobalEnv, object.size)), n)
```

If you want it as a data.frame:

```
data.frame(size = sort(sapply(.GlobalEnv, object.size))) # object name is the name of each row
```